# Issue with idle time using ReactJS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to detect the idle time and automatically show a dialog that will say "You've been inactive for a while. To keep your session active, please click the button below"

When he clicks that button, it would reset the time so it wouldn't call the logout. Right now its still calling it.

However it doesn't work well. Is there a better approach or recommended way to handling idle time in my app or is this ok?

Here is the codesandbox [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-browser-2u9z5r?file=/demo.js:868-974)

```
import { Button, Dialog } from "@mui/material";
import DialogHeader from "./components/DialogHeader";
import DialogBody from "./components/DialogBody";
import DialogFooter from "./components/DialogFooter";
import { useIdleSession } from "./hooks/useIdleSession";

function App() {
  const handleLogout = () => {
    console.log("logout");
  };

  const IDLE_CONFIG = {
    threshold: 5000, // idle time threshold in milliseconds
    timeout: 8000, // timeout duration in milliseconds
    action: handleLogout // action to be taken when timeout is reached
  };

  const { open, idleTime, handleUserActivity } = useIdleSession(IDLE_CONFIG);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
      <Dialog open={open}>
        <DialogHeader>
          {" "}
          You&#39;ve been idle for {idleTime / 1000} seconds
        </DialogHeader>

        <DialogBody>
          You&#39;ve been inactive for a while. To keep your session active,
          please click the button below
        </DialogBody>
        <DialogFooter>
          <Button
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            onClick={handleUserActivity}
          >
            Keep Session Active
          </Button>
        </DialogFooter>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**useIdleSession**

```
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

export const useIdleSession = (config) => {
  const [lastActive, setLastActive] = useState(new Date());
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [idleTime, setIdleTime] = useState(0);
  const [logoutIntervalId, setLogoutIntervalId] = useState(null);
  const isLoggedIn = true;

  //function to handle user activity
  const handleUserActivity = useCallback(() => {
    setLastActive(new Date());
    setOpen(false);
    clearTimeout(logoutIntervalId);
  }, [logoutIntervalId]);

  // useEffect to check for user activity every minute
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      // setInterval to check for user activity
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        // get current time
        const currentTime = new Date();
        // calculate idle time
        const idle = currentTime - lastActive;
        // check if user has been idle for more than the threshold time
        if (idle > config.threshold) {
          setIdleTime(idle);
          setOpen(true);
          // set a timeout to run the action if they do not click the "Keep Session Active" button
          const newLogoutIntervalId = setTimeout(config.action, config.timeout);
          setLogoutIntervalId(newLogoutIntervalId);
        }
      }, config.threshold);
      // cleanup function to clear interval when component unmounts
      // document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleUserActivity);
      // document.addEventListener('keypress', handleUserActivity);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        // document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleUserActivity);
        // document.removeEventListener('keypress', handleUserActivity);
      };
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn, lastActive, handleUserActivity, config]);

  return { open, idleTime };
};
```

Comment: We need your code for `useIdleSession` since it's a custom hook

Comment: @Samathingamajig. I already placed it in a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-browser-2u9z5r?file=/hooks/useIdleSession.js. You can fork it

Comment: @Joseph Please include all relevant information in the question itself; external links tend to rot, leaving the question useless for future users.  (That's also an awful lot of code for you to expect us to dig through; you're likeliest to get help if you construct a [mcve] demonstrating your issue)

Comment: @DanielBeck. I added it. I think thats the simplest thing it could get else you wouldnt be able to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useIdleSession` doesn't return any `handleUserActivity` property, e.g. `return { open, idleTime, handleUserActivity };`. `handleUserActivity` is undefined in calling components.

Return the declared `handleUserActivity` callback function so it can be destructured from the hook. I recommend also storing the timer/interval id in React refs so they can be used to also correctly clear any running timers on the event of component unmounting.

```js
export const useIdleSession = (config) => {
  const [lastActive, setLastActive] = useState(new Date());
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [idleTime, setIdleTime] = useState(0);

  const intervalId = useRef();
  const logoutIntervalId = useRef();

  const isLoggedIn = true;

  // function to handle user activity
  const handleUserActivity = useCallback(() => {
    setLastActive(new Date());
    setOpen(false);
    clearTimeout(logoutIntervalId.current);
  }, []);

  // Effect to return cleanup function to clear any running timers upon
  // component unmount.
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId.current);
      clearTimeout(logoutIntervalId.current);
    };
  }, []);

  // Effect to check for user activity periodically
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      // setInterval to check for user activity
      intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
        // get current time
        const currentTime = new Date();
        // calculate idle time
        const idle = currentTime - lastActive;
        // check if user has been idle for more than the threshold time
        if (idle > config.threshold) {
          setIdleTime(idle);
          setOpen(true);
          // set a timeout to run the action if they do not click the "Keep Session Active" button
          logoutIntervalId.current = setTimeout(config.action, config.timeout);
        }
      }, config.threshold);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId.current);
      };
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn, lastActive, handleUserActivity, config]);

  return { open, idleTime, handleUserActivity };
};
```

[image: Edit issue-with-idle-time-using-reactjs-and-javascript]

The `useIdleSession` hook logic can be simplified a bit. There's no need really to store a datestamp as the basic gist is to just instantiate a timeout that expires after the specified idle timeout, and upon any interactive event by a user to clear the previous timer and reinstantiate. It only needs to return a function to the component to manually reset, if/when necessary.

Example:

```
export const useIdleSession = ({ timeout, onExpire }) => {
  const timerId = useRef();

  //function to handle user activity
  const handleUserActivity = useCallback(() => {
    clearTimeout(timerId.current);
    timerId.current = setTimeout(onExpire, timeout);
  }, [onExpire, timeout]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      // Listen for user activity
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleUserActivity, {
        passive: true
      });
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleUserActivity);
      document.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserActivity);
      document.addEventListener("touchstart", handleUserActivity);

      handleUserActivity();

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleUserActivity, {
          passive: true
        });
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleUserActivity);
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserActivity);
        document.removeEventListener("touchstart", handleUserActivity);
      };
    }
  }, [ handleUserActivity]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerId.current);
    };
  }, []);

  return { reset: handleUserActivity };
};
```

[image: Edit issue-with-idle-time-using-reactjs-and-javascript (forked)]

Comment: @Joseph The first sandbox wasn't doing anything to listen for activity events (*the event listeners were commented out*) so I assumed your question/issue was about the modal not resetting the timers. This second sandbox/implementation looks to be a little more lean though.

Comment: @Joseph Just gave the second sandbox another look and I don't see much I'd want/need to change. It seems to work and looks ok.

Comment: @Joseph The last time I had to create an idle timer it was back in the React class component days, but the approach is logical (*reset a timeout for each interaction*) for a custom hook. I'm not sure where or how the `isLoggedIn` value will be worked in, but like I said, the rest looks ok.